# Find JSON sibling with no parent using JsonNode in java

Tags: java, json, jersey-client

I have a JSON object as follows:

```
[
    {
        "name":"thisIsAName",
        "id":1
    },
    {
        "name":"anotherName",
        "id":2
    },
    {
        "name":"anotherName2",
        "id":3
    }
]
```

and am trying to locate the id based on the name.  How do you navigate to the sibling when there is no parent?  I'm getting the JSON from a Jersey Client response:

```
Response responseObject = client.getAllObjects();
JsonNode responseAsNode = responseObject.readEntity(JsonNode.class);
```

If I search by name:  `responseAsNode.findValue("name");`, then it correctly gives me a `List<JsonNode>` that contains every name element, so I can search that for the one that matches my expected, but it only returns a list of JsonNodes of `"name":"value",`.

```
for (JsonNode node : responseAsNode.findValues("name")){
    if (node.textValue().equals("ftp-" + DEFAULT_ENV.toLowerCase()))    {
        //Now, find my id and do something with it.

        break;
    }
}
```

If I call `node.getParent()`, I get an exception as there is no parent.  Other than asking the developers to add `"list":` to the front of the Json, what should I try?

Comment: Figure out your position in the array, using i in your for loop.  You will be able to then get the id with responseAsNode.get(i).get("id")

Comment: It's so simple, I feel dumb for missing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate the JSON tree, and try to match each element.

```
String toFind = "anotherName";

Iterator<JsonNode> iter = responseAsNode.elements();

while (iter.hasNext())
{
    JsonNode node = iter.next();

    JsonNode name = node.get("name");

    if (toFind.equals(name.asText()))
    {
        System.out.println(node.get("id").asLong());
    }

}
```

This will print `2`.

Comment: Awesome!  This would work also.  Man, I stare at something long enough and I can't see beyond my nose.  Thanks, @starf.

Comment: @RyanCox Don't be too hard on yourself, we've all been there.